# How to to join anonymous types based on some initial conditions

Tags: .net, linq, predicate

I'm using Linq to equi-join a table as follow:

```
var res= from t0 in table join t1 in table on new { t0.column0, t0.column1...}
equals { t1.column0,t2.column1...} select new { val1= t0.column0, val2=t0.column2}.
```

Now, i would like to have the columns included based on some predefined conditions. This means that i would like to end up with a subset of the columns instead of all of them otherwise. the columns that will be mactched will depend of some user choices.

How can this be done using linq?

Best
B

Comment: That's not a cross-join - that's an equi-join. For a cross-join, use multiple "from" clauses. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve at the moment - please give more context, ideally with a short but complete example. (It's odd for the result shape to depend on a condition... what would you expect the compile-time type to do?)

Comment: sorry for the typo. yes, i did not mean a cross join. I want to find similar records in the tables that have the same value in the those columns. Just that the list of columns have to be dynamic

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean, to be honest. As I said before, a complete example would be clearer. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: Well, I will try again. sometime i only want my query to return values for whch column0 and columns 7 matches. other time, i column3 and column4 matches. I want a dynamic matching column criteria.

Comment: You probably want to build the query dynamically then, either using expression trees or Dynamic LINQ.

Comment: I looked up expression trees, the example provided was too simple http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

Comment: Well yes, examples tend to be simple. That doesn't mean you can't use expression trees for this. It really doesn't feel like a terribly good fit for LINQ though, which typically gives you *compile-time* safety (to at least some extent).

Comment: Thank you. Dynamic linq looks like what i need.